# How to get neighbor points in high dimensional space?

Tags: geometry

I am writing to write an algorithm to do neighbor points search (so the implicit form will not work). We define neighbor points as the points with Euclidean distance $r$ to a given point.

In 2D, for point $(a_1,a_2)$ the neighbor can be written as

$$
x_1=r\cos(\theta)+a_1\\
x_2=r\sin(\theta)+a_2
$$

For such equation with parametric form / sphere coordinate, I can write code to generate all the points. But how about in 5D?, how to write the equation in sphere coordiante for ($x_1,x_2, \cdots x_5$)?

Comment: I think you want those minus signs to be pluses. For example, you certainly want $(2,0)$ to be in the $1$-neighborhood of $(1,0)$, and $x_1 = 2 = 1 + 1 = r\cos(0) + a$.

Comment: @AlexProvost thanks, fixed.

Comment: It seems like you want a way to write hyper spherical coordinates.

Comment: Thanks @RodrigodeAzevedo, I equation, but how can you write a parametric form? implicit form would not be helpful for generate the data points

Comment: @hxd1011 What exactly do you want to do? To search points or to generate points? Give the algorithm's inputs and outputs.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo sorry for the confusion. I think my question is equal to asking how to write down a hyper-sphere equation in spherical coordinates..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In dimension $n$, and for a fixed radius $r$ and base point $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$, you are looking for the coordinates of the points lying on the $(n-1)$-sphere centered at $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. The best you can do to generalize your previous effort is to use [generalized spherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Spherical_coordinates). This will let you generate the points $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ in the $r$-neighborhood using $(n-1)$ angular coordinates.

For example, in dimension $3$, it would look like
$$\begin{align}
x_1 &= r\cos(\phi_1) + a_1\\
x_2 &= r\sin(\phi_1)\cos(\phi_2) + a_2 \\
x_3 &= r\sin(\phi_1)\sin(\phi_2) + a_3. \end{align}$$

Comment: Great! this is the answer I wanted. I searched up to 4D case, here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersphere.html , but did not find the link you mentioned. Thanks for the pointer.